# Information from the list and display on map

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, point

How do I get NIMI1 and the coordinates from the array and print them out on the page using javascript. I would also like to display the coordinates as a marker on a leaflet map. This is also a part of a larger list and this is the first one so the index is [0]?

```
"features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "FID": 5001,
                "SOLMUTUNNU": "1548112",
                "LYHYTTUNNU": "H4684",
                "SOLMUTYYPP": "P",
                "X": 2564475,
                "Y": 6679388,
                "PROJ_X": 2564469,
                "PROJ_Y": 6679361,
                "NIMI1": "Niinilahti",
                "NAMN1": "Bastviken",
                "NIMI2": "Niinisaarentie",
                "NAMN2": "Bastövägen",
                "REI_VOIM": 1,
                "AIK_VOIM": 1,
                "VERKKO": 1
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    25.160047347437963,
                    60.2208899317569
                ]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add javascript function and button like below and see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <script>
  function arrayFunction() {
  var array = //your full array with semicolon 
  var myarray = array.indexOf("NIMI1");
  document.getElementById("new_array").innerHTML = myarray;

     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = myarray;
  }
 </script>

  <p id="new_array"></p>
  <button onclick="arrayFunction()">NIMI1</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way java script !== javascript